# Ontology to semantic search with Apache Solr

Tags: solr, search-engine, ontology, semantic-web, protege

I'd like to implement a Semantic search engine using Apache solr. For this I desing an Ontology, but I don't know the best way to implement it in the search engine. Can Someone help me with ideas, please!